# Writing a malloc'd C struct to a file, and reading from it

Tags: c, file, struct, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct stCrimeArchive {
   char id_student[10];
   int id_document;
   char judgement[30];
   int id_crime;
   char date[12];
   char id_police[12];
};

int main()
{
   struct stCrimeArchive *regi;
   FILE *filea;
   filea = fopen("crimearchives.dat", "r+b");          
   if(!filea) 
 filea = fopen("crimearchives.dat", "w+b");

   int i;
   char num[6];

   regi = (struct stCrimeArchive*)malloc (sizeof(struct stCrimeArchive));

   printf("ID DOCUMENT: ");
   fgets(num, 6, stdin);
   regi->id_document= atoi(num);

   printf("ID STUDENT: ");
   fgets(regi->id_student, 30, stdin);
   for(i = strlen(regi->id_student)-1; i && regi->id_student[i] < ' '; i--)
    regi->id_student[i] = 0;

   printf("CRIME CODE: ");
   fgets(num, 6, stdin);
   regi->id_crime = atoi(num);

   printf("DATE OF THE CRIME: ");
   fgets(regi->date, 30, stdin);
   for(i = strlen(regi->date)-1; i && regi->date[i] < ' '; i--)
    regi->date[i] = 0;   

   printf("ID POLICE: ");
   fgets(regi->id_police, 30, stdin);
   for(i = strlen(regi->id_police)-1; i && regi->id_police[i] < ' '; i--)
    regi->id_police[i] = 0;  

   printf("JUDGEMENT: ");
   fgets(regi->judgement, 30, stdin);
   for(i = strlen(regi->judgement)-1; i && regi->judgement[i] < ' '; i--)
    regi->judgement[i] = 0;     

   fseek(filea, 0, SEEK_END);
   fwrite(&regi, sizeof(struct stCrimeArchive*), 1, filea);

   free(regi);
   fclose(filea);
}
```

The context is the following: I am making a variable length file, and on it i'm writing many crime archive with the struct shown above. To do it i need to do a malloc for the struct involved. The problem is when I write it to file, it doesn't write anything, and I don't know what mistake(s) I'm doing.

Also I want to read the crime archives from the same file, but I also don't know what I am doing wrong. Here's the code for what I am trying to do:

```
int main()
{ 
   struct stCrimeArchive *regi;
   regi = (struct stCrimeArchive*)malloc (sizeof(struct stCrimeArchive));
   FILE *filea;
   filea = fopen("crimearchives.dat", "r+b");          
   if(!filea) 
    filea = fopen("crimearchives.dat", "w+b");
   rewind(filea);
   while  (fread(&regi, sizeof(struct stCrimeArchive), 1, filea))
    printf("%2d %-11s %-11s %8d %-13s %-14s\n", regi->id_document, regi->id_police, regi->date, regi->id_crime, regi->id_student, regi->judgement);
   fclose(filea);
}
```

Comment: You are writing a pointer to the file.  Are you saying you are getting zero-length file?

Comment: You probably don't want to write a pointer, by the way.  It isn't going to mean anything to any other process.

Comment: The idea is to write the struct, but the declaration of the struct is with pointers.

Comment: Sorry if I answer obvious things about the program. 1. This is something who I had to translate from spanish to look for help in here. 2. I don't handle very well pointer topics with words. I was trapped with this situation and i didn't know how to solve this, so I was forced to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to write the size of the struct and not the size of the pointer to the struct.

```
 fwrite(regi, sizeof(struct stCrimeArchive), 1, filea);
```

Or maybe this would be more clear:

```
 fwrite(regi, sizeof(*regi), 1, filea);
```

Comment: Actually from his code, I doubt he needs to use dynamic allocation at all.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer, but I finished my proyect and this was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If I was you, I'd forget about using `malloc` at all, from your example. You don't need dynamic memory allocation for this.

```
struct CrimeArchive regi;
regi.id_student = 42;
/* do all your stuff here */

FILE* fp = fopen("crimearchives.dat", "wb");
if (fp != NULL) {
    if (fwrite(&regi, sizeof regi, 1, fp) != 1)
       { /* handle error */ }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Same when you read from it:

```
struct CrimeArchive regi;

FILE* fp = fopen("crimearchives.dat", "rb");
if (fp != NULL) {
   if (fread(&regi, sizeof regi, 1, fp) != 1)
       { /* handle error */ }

   fclose(fp);
}
```

And remember, writing and reading structs to/from files like this is not guaranteed to be portable if the file is written to on a system and read from on another system.

Comment: In context, the above program is part of a greater proyect where also I have fixed length files, and the solution you are proposing is already implemented on this type of files.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fwrite` call is wrong:

```
fwrite(regi, sizeof(struct stCrimeArchive*), 1, filea);
```

It's right that you're passing a pointer to the memory to be written, it's wrong that the size is that of a pointer and not the size of the actual `struct` you're intending to write. Chances are you'll only be writing 4 or 8 bytes of the start of the `struct` to file.

Change `sizeof(struct stCrimeArchive*)` to `sizeof(struct stCrimeArchive)`, the same size you pass to `malloc`.

However, your code still doesn't compile since there's no such type `stCrimeArchive` (should be `CrimeArchive`?) and another reason being that you you're trying to assign an `int` to `char[]` in the following line:

```
regi->id_student = atoi(num);
```

Comment: About the second issue, I was adapting the code quickly so you guys can see it in English, so it's natural it would be an error here. That issue can be corrected perfectly. My general problem is the first one, so let me check it out.

Comment: I couldn't check if the fwrite was right because in the second program executing it I got a segfault in the same line of the printf (checked with gcc + valgrind).

Answer (score 0):

```
while  (fread(&regi, sizeof(struct CrimeArchive), 1, filea))
```

I think the fread should accept void* but not void ** here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering this very late, but I want to let know how the problem was solved. One of the answers was right, the problem was to write the size of the struct.

For the writing process:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct stCrimeArchive {
   char id_student[10];
   int id_document;
   char judgement[30];
   int id_crime;
   char date[12];
   char id_police[12];
};

int main()
{
   struct stCrimeArchive *regi;
   FILE *filea;
   filea = fopen("crimearchives.dat", "r+b");          
   if(!filea) 
 filea = fopen("crimearchives.dat", "w+b");

   int i;
   char num[6];

   regi = (struct stCrimeArchive*)malloc (sizeof(struct stCrimeArchive));

   printf("ID DOCUMENT: ");
   fgets(num, 6, stdin);
   regi->id_document= atoi(num);

   printf("ID STUDENT: ");
   fgets(regi->id_student, 30, stdin);
   for(i = strlen(regi->id_student)-1; i && regi->id_student[i] < ' '; i--)
    regi->id_student[i] = 0;

   printf("CRIME CODE: ");
   fgets(num, 6, stdin);
   regi->id_crime = atoi(num);

   printf("DATE OF THE CRIME: ");
   fgets(regi->date, 30, stdin);
   for(i = strlen(regi->date)-1; i && regi->date[i] < ' '; i--)
    regi->date[i] = 0;   

   printf("ID POLICE: ");
   fgets(regi->id_police, 30, stdin);
   for(i = strlen(regi->id_police)-1; i && regi->id_police[i] < ' '; i--)
    regi->id_police[i] = 0;  

   printf("JUDGEMENT: ");
   fgets(regi->judgement, 30, stdin);
   for(i = strlen(regi->judgement)-1; i && regi->judgement[i] < ' '; i--)
    regi->judgement[i] = 0;     

   fseek(filea, 0, SEEK_END);
   fwrite(regi, sizeof *regi, 1, filea);

   free(regi);
   fclose(filea);
}
```

And then, for the reading process:

```
int main()
{ 
   struct stCrimeArchive *regi;
   regi = (struct stCrimeArchive*)malloc (sizeof(struct stCrimeArchive));
   FILE *filea;
   filea = fopen("crimearchives.dat", "r+b");          
   if(!filea) 
    filea = fopen("crimearchives.dat", "w+b");
   rewind(filea);
   while  (fread(regi, sizeof *regi, 1, filea))
    printf("%2d %-11s %-11s %8d %-13s %-14s\n", regi->id_document, regi->id_police, regi->date, regi->id_crime, regi->id_student, regi->judgement);
   fclose(filea);
}
```

I have nothing more to say but thanks =)